# rails haml and select tag in form with id (class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have this code:

```
= f.select(:manufacturer_id, 
           VehicleManufacturer.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, 
           :selected => f.object.manufacturer_id, 
           required: true, 
           id: "manufacturer-select")
```

and I try to set an id or class to my selectbox, but it didn't work, also I tried

```
= f.select(:manufacturer_id, 
           VehicleManufacturer.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, 
           {:selected => f.object.manufacturer_id}, 
           required: true, 
           id: "manufacturer-select")
```

then it worked, I saw right id, but I didn't see the selected item... How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to Rails API documentation:

```
select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

So, try:

```
= f.select(:manufacturer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(VehicleManufacturer.all, :id, :name, @object.manufacturer_id ), {}, required: true, id: "manufacturer-select")
```

Comment: undefined method `manufacturer_id' for nil:NilClass   i get, and also how to select then in edit action from list...

Comment: `@object` is an example. User the variable you have in `form_for`.